# Best way to avoid explicit casts

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, casting, polymorphism

I have a class hierarchy like below

```
Vehicle
|_ TransaportationVehicle has method getLoadCapacity
|_ PassengerVehicle has method getPassengerCapacity
```

and I have one more class `Booking` it have a reference to `Vehicle`.

Now whenever I have to call `getPassengerCapacity` or `getLoadCapacity` on `vehicle` reference I need to type cast vehicle to its concrete implementation like `((PassengerVehicle)vehicle).getPassengerCapacity()` and this type of calls spans over multiple parts in the project. So is there any way with which I can avoid these type of casts and my code will look beautiful and clean?

*Note: These are not actual classes I have taken these as an example to demonstrate current problem.*

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, when booking a `Vehicle` you need to distinguish at some point whether it’s a `TransportationVehicle` or a `PassengerVehicle` as both have different properties.

The easiest way would be to initiate two different `Booking` processes: one for vehicles that can transport goods, and one for vehicles that can transport passengers. As for how to differentiate between these two types of vehicles: you could add `canTransportPassengers()` and `canTransportGoods()` methods to `Vehicle`, the subclasses would then override these methods to return `true` where appropriate. Also, this way a vehicle that can transport both is possible, like a train.

Comment: how this will avoid typecasting effort?

Comment: It will restrict casting to the single point where you are creating your `Booking` process: it already knows whether it takes a `TransportationVehicle` or a `PassengerVehicle`. Alternatively, you could move the capacity-related methods into `Vehicle` itself and not care at all about any subclasses, only about their exposed capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to use different method names then You must cast to concrete class.

But if You can make this methods return same type value and have same names You can use polymorphism for it. Create abstract method in `Vehicle` class and override it in each child.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way I would accomplish this is to create a Generified `Booking` parent class.

```
public abstract class Booking<V extends Vehicle> {

    protected abstract V getVehicle();
}

public class TransportationVehicleBooking extends Booking<TransaportationVehicle> {

    @Override
    protected TransaportationVehicle getVehicle() {
        return new TransaportationVehicle();
    }
}

public class PassengerVehicleBooking extends Booking<PassengerVehicle> {

    @Override
    protected PassengerVehicle getVehicle() {
        return new PassengerVehicle();
    }
}
```

Your `Booking` class will have all the logic that spans all the booking subclasses and some abstract method each subclasses will need to do effective calculations.

Then all you have to do is have reference to a `Booking` class and calling the relevant method required without having to worry about the "logistics" (get it) of the booking itself.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You method overriding concepts. You need to have all these method in the Parent class and same can be overriden in the child clasees.

You can then access all the methods from super class using Runtime polymorphism

**Vehicle**

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public int getCapacity();
}
```

**TransaportationVehicle**

```
public class TransaportationVehicle implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public int getCapacity() {
        return getLoadCapacity();
    }

    private int getLoadCapacity() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**PassengerVehicle**

```
public class PassengerVehicle implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public int getCapacity() {
        return getPassengerCapacity();
    }

    private int getPassengerCapacity() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

***USAGE***

```
Vehicle passenger = new PassengerVehicle();
passenger.getCapacity();

Vehicle transaportation = new TransaportationVehicle();
transaportation.getCapacity()
```

Comment: so you mean I need to have method that returns concrete class reference in base for all classes in hierarchy?

Comment: No You need to have those method defined in the parent class and these should be overriden in the child class.

Comment: Ok, so how would a `Bus` work seeing that it *is-a* transport vehicle that can accommodate both passengers and load? So is a `Aeroplane`, `CruiseBoat`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that passenger capacity is always an integer and load capacity could very well a big number depending on what is the unit for load. I would go ahead and create Vehicle class as follow:

```
class Vehicle {
    Number capacity; 
    public Number getCapacity() {
        return capacity; 
    }
    public void setCapacity(Number capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity; 
    }
}
```

The reason I am using `Number` is so that I then use Integer in `PassengerVehicle` class and Double in `TransporatationVehicle` and that is because `Integer` and `Double` are subtype of `Number` and you can get away with a cast.

```
class TransportationVehicle extends Vehicle {
    @Override 
    public Double getCapacity() {
        //all I have to do is cast Number to Double
        return (Double) capacity; 
    }

    @Override 
    public void setCapacity(Number capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity; 
    }
}
```

Similarly the `PassengerVehicle` class as follow:

```
class PassengerVehicle extends Vehicle {
    @Override 
    public Integer getCapacity() {
        //Cast to Integer and works because Integer is subtype of Number
        return (Integer) capacity; 
    }

    @Override 
    public void setCapacity(Number capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity; 
    }
}
```

You can then use above classes to create vehicle object as follow:

```
public class Booking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        Vehicle transportationVehicle = new TransportationVehicle();
        //assigning Double to setCapacity
        transportationVehicle.setCapacity(new Double(225.12));


        Vehicle passengerVehicle = new PassengerVehicle(); 
        //assigning Integer to setCapacity
        passengerVehicle.setCapacity(5);

        System.out.println(transportationVehicle.getCapacity()); 
        // output: 225.12
        System.out.println(passengerVehicle.getCapacity());
        // output: 5
    }
}
```

On the side notes if you try to pass `TransportationVehicle` anything but Number or Double then you will get Exception and similarly if you pass `PassengerVehicle` anything but Number or Integer you will get exception.

I know that I am deviating from the scope of your question but, I really want to show how you can make your methods generics. This allow you to decide to return type of `getCapacity()` during coding which is very flexible. See below:

```
class Vehicle<T> {
    //generic type T
    T capacity; 

    //generic method getCapacity
    public T getCapacity() {
        return capacity; 
    }

    //generic method setCapacity 
    public void setCapacity(T capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity; 
    }
}

class TransportationVehicle<T> extends Vehicle<T> {
    @Override 
    public T getCapacity() {
        return capacity; 
    }

    @Override 
    public void setCapacity(T capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity; 
    }
}

class PassengerVehicle<T> extends Vehicle<T> {
    @Override 
    public T getCapacity() {
        return capacity; 
    }

    @Override 
    public void setCapacity(T capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity; 
    }
}
```

As you can see above the generic methods and you can use them as follow:

```
Vehicle<String> vehicleString = new TransportationVehicle<String>();
vehicleString.setCapacity("Seriously!"); //no problem

Vehicle<Integer> vehicleInteger = new PassengerVehicle<Integer>(); 
vehicleInteger.setCapacity(3); //boxing done automatically

Vehicle<Double> vehicleDouble = new PassengerVehicle<Double>(); 
vehicleDouble.setCapacity(2.2); //boxing done automatically
```

You can decide the type while coding and if you supply a `Vehicle<String>` with capacity as `Integer` then you will get compile time error, so you won't be allowed.

```
System.out.println(vehicleString.getCapacity()); 
//output: Seriously!
System.out.println(vehicleInteger.getCapacity());
//output:  3 
System.out.println(vehicleDouble.getCapacity());
//output: 2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to extract an abstract method suitable for all vehicles. If you can't do this you can also use an often forgotten pattern - the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). E.g.

Introduce a visitor interface

```
public interface VehicleVisitor {
    public void visit(TransportationVehicle transportationVehicle);
    public void visit(PassengerVehicle passengerVehicle);
}
```

add an `accept` method to the `Vehicle`

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public void accept(VehicleVisitor visitor);
}
```

implement the accept method in the sub classes

```
public class PassengerVehicle implements Vehicle {

    private int passengerCapacity;

    public static PassengerVehicle withPassengerCapacity(int passengerCapacity) {
        return new PassengerVehicle(passengerCapacity);

    }

    private PassengerVehicle(int passengerCapacity) {
        this.passengerCapacity = passengerCapacity;
    }

    public int getPassengerCapacity() {
        return passengerCapacity;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(VehicleVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);

    }
}

public class TransportationVehicle implements Vehicle {

    private int loadCapacity;

    public static TransportationVehicle withLoadCapacity(int loadCapacity) {
        return new TransportationVehicle(loadCapacity);

    }

    private TransportationVehicle(int loadCapacity) {
        this.loadCapacity = loadCapacity;
    }

    public int getLoadCapacity() {
        return loadCapacity;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(VehicleVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

implement a visitor...

```
public class LoadSupported implements VehicleVisitor {

    private boolean supported;
    private int load;

    public LoadSupported(int load) {
        this.load = load;
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return supported;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(TransportationVehicle transportationVehicle) {
        int loadCapacity = transportationVehicle.getLoadCapacity();
        supported = load <= loadCapacity;

    }

    @Override
    public void visit(PassengerVehicle passengerVehicle) {
        supported = false;
    }

}
```

...and use it

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransportationVehicle transportationVehicle1 = TransportationVehicle
                .withLoadCapacity(5);
        TransportationVehicle transportationVehicle2 = TransportationVehicle
                .withLoadCapacity(10);
        PassengerVehicle passengerVehicle = PassengerVehicle
                .withPassengerCapacity(5);

        LoadSupported loadSupported = new LoadSupported(7);

        supportsLoad(transportationVehicle1, loadSupported);
        supportsLoad(transportationVehicle2, loadSupported);
        supportsLoad(passengerVehicle, loadSupported);

    }

    private static void supportsLoad(Vehicle vehicle,
            LoadSupported loadSupported) {
        vehicle.accept(loadSupported);
        System.out.println(vehicle.getClass().getSimpleName() + "[" + System.identityHashCode(vehicle) + "]" + " does"
                + (loadSupported.isSupported() ? " " : " not ")
                + "support load capacity");
    }
}
```

The output will be something like this

```
TransportationVehicle[778966024] does not support load capacity
TransportationVehicle[1021653256] does support load capacity
PassengerVehicle[1794515827] does not support load capacity
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the example. How do you realize that you are dealing with a concrete type in the first place? Are you instanceOf-ing? Are you type matching?

If so your problem is way past casting...

Anyways when you have objects that must belong to the same family and algorithms which are not abstract and change according to the object being handled you typically use some sort of [behavioral pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) like visitor, or the [Bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).